# mmap(): what happens if underlying file changes (shrinks)?

Tags: c++, linux, mmap

If you memory map a file using mmap(), but then the underlying file changes to a much smaller size. What happens if you access a memory offset that was shaved off from the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IBM says it is undefined http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2Fmmap.htm

> If the size of the mapped file is decreased after mmap(), attempts to reference beyond the end of the file **are undefined** and may result in an MCH0601 exception.
>
> If the size of the file increases after the mmap() function completes, then the whole pages beyond the original end of file will not be accessible via the mapping.

The same is said in SingleUnixSpecification: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/mmap.html

> If the size of the mapped file changes after the call to mmap() as a result of some other operation on the mapped file, the effect of references to portions of the mapped region that correspond to added or removed portions of the **file is unspecified**.

'undefined' or 'unspecified' means - the OS is allowed to start formatting of disk or anything. Most probable is SIGSEGV-killing your application.

Comment: I'd say it's one case where UB could end uo being running into OS bugs causing data loss: http://lwn.net/Articles/357767/

Comment: @osgx On Linux, it's a `SIGBUS`.

Answer (score -2):

According to the man pages mmap returns EINVAL error when you try to access an address that is too large for the current file mapping.

"dnotify" and "inotify" are the current file change notification services in the Linux kernel. 
Presumably, they would inform the mmap subsystem of changes to the file.

Comment: What if file is made shorter after the mmap is returned? There will be no chance to get error from mmap call.

Comment: I just tried that using stat to calculate the size of the file, I mmaped the file, printed out the entire contents, slept for 5 seconds (while I removed a few lines) and printed out the entire contents again, using the stat variable (unmodified from my original stat call), it worked fine, and printed out the contracted contents.

Comment: Gearoid Murphy, this is very unreliable, because it depends of linux disk cache (page cache) usage and on type of mapping.